# Ошибка в работе с EditorUtility в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Создал скрипт, который пользуется библиотекой `UnityEditor` и в нем используется класс EditorUtility, для вызова проводника, чтобы выдать путь к файлу. В самом Unity удается удачно протестировать программу, однако при сборке выдает ошибку:
`Assets\CreatePack.cs(242,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EditorUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`
Не понимаю где именно я не указал ссылку, учитывая, что на тесте все работает.

Если нужно. прилагаю вырезку самого кода:

```
string path = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Open picture", "", "png,jpg");
BinaryQimage = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);

texture.LoadImage(BinaryQimage);

Qimage.texture = texture;
```

(Все try-catch убрал, чтобы не загромождать)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пространство имен `UnityEditor` доступно только в редакторе. Соответственно, при компиляции это работать не будет.

Используйте

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

<...>

#if UNITY_EDITOR
string path = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Open picture", "", "png,jpg");
BinaryQimage = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
texture.LoadImage(BinaryQimage);
Qimage.texture = texture;
#endif
```

Но помните, что вне редактора Вам нужно будет открывать проводник другим образом.